# Not able to import Localization library in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, localization, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import Localization library in python 3.7 in Jupyter notebooks but everytime it shows this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ca0ae5a2ecfb> in <module>()
      2 from skimage.measure import regionprops
      3 import matplotlib.patches as patches
----> 4 import localization

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\localization\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from geoProject import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geoProject'
```

I have no project named 'geoProject' either.

Answer (score 0):

It is not your fault. `geoProject` seems to be another file in that project.

https://github.com/kamalshadi/Localization/blob/master/localization/geoProject.py

It is not being imported correctly inside the `localization` module at the `__init__.py` file

Comment: You can either create a bug in the github repo and ask the author to fix it or fix it yourself